# Group by date and show in date time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, count

i want to count the data then group by date (and it show in date time). the result of data type must date time not var char. any idea ?

table_a

```
timestamp
2020-11-28 04:00:00
2020-11-28 05:00:00
2020-11-29 01:00:00
2020-11-29 02:00:00
2020-11-29 03:00:00
```

expected result:

```
timestamp                 count
2020-11-28 00:00:00       2
2020-11-29 00:00:00       3
```

if i query this:

```
select date(timestamp), count(*) as count
from table_a
group by date(timestamp)
```

the result is:

```
timestamp     count
2020-11-28     2
2020-11-29     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the time part with `DATE(timestamp)` and cast back to `DATETIME` with the function `CAST()`:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE(timestamp) AS DATETIME) AS my_datetime, 
       COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM table_a
GROUP BY my_datetime;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bdbb9064aa84d196d52c53f73fde8f99).
Results:

```
> my_datetime         | count
> :------------------ | ----:
> 2020-11-28 00:00:00 |     2
> 2020-11-29 00:00:00 |     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

`CAST(MED_TO_DT AS DATETIME)`

You can use `CAST` date field to datetime.

Comment: CAST(DATEFILED AS DATETIME)

I MEANT THIS INSTEAD I COPY PASTE MY CODE

Comment: Please avoid all caps text. You can edit your answer instead of commenting with changes.

Comment: first answer .will improve

Comment: the result not group by date @suhairsha

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by the date AND time, use this query:

```
select CONVERT(timestamp, datetime) as timestamp, count(1) as count
from table_a
group by CONVERT(timestamp, datetime)
```

Otherwise, if you truly want to group by the date ONLY and then display the timestamp as 00:00:00, then use this query:

```
select CONVERT(CONVERT(timestamp, date), datetime) as timestamp, count(1) as count
from table_a
group by CONVERT(timestamp, date)
```

Comment: i got error  "unknown data type CONVERT" @KKJ

Comment: Good point, I was using MSSQL to run my query. In MySql, I believe the data type and data value are be swapped in the CONVERT function - I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL :

```
SELECT Concat(Cast(timestamp AS DATE), " 00:00:00") AS timestamps, 
       Count(*)                                     AS count 
FROM   table_a 
GROUP  BY timestamps
```

Comment: the results same as with me before, "show by date" but i want to show in date time @kelvin

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @hinafaya how about concatenating date with "00:00:00" to get desired Output?

Comment: thank you, i fixed the issue with CAST(DATE(timestamp) AS DATETIME) then group by datetime @kelvin

Comment: Keep practice of accepting answers and upvoting answers if you feel it solves or helps the problem